# Image alt text render error when using link (with final rendering different than preview)

Tags: bug, markdown, images

When you declare an image the usual way it works:

```
![alt text][1]
```

[image]

With links as alt text it works as well:

```
![http://x][1]
```

[image: http://x]

**But when you use a `-` before a link:**

```
![- http://x][1]
```

It does not render the image and generates an invalid HTML text output instead (with final rendering different than preview <sup>([thanks @animuson](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183592/219205))</sup>):

- When in preview the rendered text is `http://x" title="" />`.
- In the final post, the rendered text is `http://x">`. See it below:

http://x">

---

Anything else works: `![- http://][1]`, `![- bla][1]`, `![- http:/x][1]`.

Comment: That difference is just because when you don't enter a title, one Markdown engine creates empty title attributes, while the other one creates none at all.

Answer (score 2):

This is most likely the auto-linkifier acting up again. A `[` character is not a valid preceder for auto-linkification. A space character, however, is. Apparently a `]` is also a valid end character that stops a hyperlink (or perhaps it's seeing the end of the string depending on what order things get processed), so your `![- http://x][1]` ends up looking like this after it runs through Markdown:

```
<img src="<a href="http://x">http://x</a>" title="" />
```

Once that runs through the sanitizer to remove invalid HTML:

```
<img src="<a href="http://x">http://x</a>" title="" />
```

and that's how you end up with the odd result in the rendering.

**Note:** Oddly enough, the title attribute only seems to get added in the post preview as you're typing, but doesn't get added in the final rendering of the post. *shrugs*

Comment: +1: Good catch on pointing out the difference in preview and final rendered text! I didnt notice it!